# vmware-mount not Connecting to remote ESXi Server

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to use `vmware-mount` version 1.2.1 to mount a virtual disk from an ESXi 4.1.0 server on Ubuntu 10.04.  My command line looks like this:

```
sudo vmware-mount -v "datastore/VSA1" -h 192.168.100.100 -u username -F password.txt "[datastore] VSA1/VSA1.vmdk" /mount/remote-vm
```

I'm not sure if that line is correct, since their documentation lists `-i` as a parameter, which isn't actually accepted by the tool.  The point is, I always get this error:

```
Failed to mount disk '[datastore] VSA1/VSA1.vmdk': Cannot open the virtual disk
```

Is there any way to put it into verbose mode or something so that it actually gives me some information as to *why* it fails to open the virtual disk?  So far, I've used my method of wireshark to listen to TCP 902, which shows that there is no activity on that port.  So it makes sense that it can't connect, because as far as I can tell, it isn't even *trying*.

I'm at a complete loss here.